# Auto-Gmail Labeler is not performing as expected

Tags: google-apps-script

I need help with a simple Google Apps script that applies a label to an email based on some search criteria. For example, for any email older_than:5y, apply label "Old Email."
This is what I've come up with so far:

```
function addLabel() {
var threads = GmailApp.search('Older_than:5y');
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Downloaded and Saved");

for (var t in threads) {
  threads[t].addLabel(label);
}
}
```

When I ran it, it applied the label to some of the emails that were older than 5 years, but it seems to have stopped after a couple hundred, and I don’t know why.

Maybe the issue is that I am applying the label to a thread rather than emails?

Comment: Check documentation for `search`(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery): > Where the thread size is unknown, and potentially very large, please use the 'paged' call

Comment: [This example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail#list_inbox_snippets) may be helpful.